# Dynamic obstacles and teb_local_planner

Tags: ros, teb-local-planner, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

When addressing the problem of dynamic obstacles avoidance with my mobile base, I came across this [solution](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner/Tutorials/Incorporate%20dynamic%20obstacles). The mentioned tutorial assumes some node is publishing [costmap_converter/ObstacleMsg](http://docs.ros.org/api/costmap_converter/html/msg/ObstacleMsg.html)s on a pre-defined topic. In that case, a toy python node is publishing a fake obstacle moving in y direction.

What I'm interested in, is in having a proper way to detect dynamic obstacles and let the teb_local_planner consider them for planning. In the [main](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner) wiki page, the documentation of the `include_dynamic_obstacles` parameter states that:

```
~<name>/include_dynamic_obstacles (bool, default: false)

    If this parameter is set to true, the motion of obstacles with non-zero velocity (provided via user-supplied obstacles on topic ~/obstacles or obtained from the costmap_converter) is predicted and considered during optimization via a constant velocity model. New
```

Therefore I'd be very interested to know how to obtain dynamic obstacles from the `costmap_converter`.

Please, can someone show me how to do that?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328646/dynamic-obstacles-and-teb_local_planner/) by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2019-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

the teb_local_planner considers two different sources for obstacle information:

- local costmap (costmap_2d)
- costmap_converter/ObstacleMsgs

The most common option for using the navigation stack with teb_local_planner is to use costmap information.
However, the costmap information does not contain any time information and therefore only provides a static view of the environment in each sampling interval.
In addition, ObstacleMsgs can be used to provide obstacle information on the associated topic.

Tracking obstacles and predicting their motion (or simplified: their current velocity) usually requires non-trivial algorithms operating with raw sensor data. A proper robotic system therefore includes a separate tracking node that provides the planner with this type of information (e.g., [via message api](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner/Tutorials/Incorporate%20dynamic%20obstacles)).

However, a simple tracking algorithm has been integrated into the costmap_converter package to identify dynamic obstacles that are based on changes in the costmap and not on raw data. The advantage is that it can be used with minimal configuration and any sensor sources supported by costmap_2d, but with lower accuracy and delay. You can check if the performance is suitable for your setup and application.
See [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner/Tutorials/Track%20and%20include%20dynamic%20obstacles%20via%20costmap_converter) for a tutorial on how to use this feature.

Cheers,
Christoph

Edit: The current implementation uses a constant-velocity model to predict the obstacles' future movement.

---

Originally posted by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) with karma: 2531 on 2019-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2